# FATAL: Module hello.ko not found

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, kernel-modules

I'm using `CentOS-6.5` and default kernel is `2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64`. I downloaded `2.6.32` and built that kernel (under `/lib/modules/2.6.32`).

I wrote a module for simple `hello world` program. This program is working under below case:

Makefile: `/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build`          (default kernel)

```
$ sudo insmod hello.ko

$ dmesg
module inserted..
hello world..
```

My program is not working for below case:

Makefile: `/lib/modules/3.2.32/build`                     (newly built kernel)

```
$ sudo insmod hello.ko
insmod: error inserting 'hello.ko': -1 Invalid module format

dmesg: 
hello: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
```

I tried `modprobe` for both cases it is showing below error

`FATAL: Module hello not found.`

How compile my module with `2.6.32` kernel?

Answer (score 2):

The Linux kernel contains data structures whose layout varies not only from version to version but also depending on the compilation options. As a consequence, when you compile a kernel module, you need to have not only the header files from the kernel source, but also some header files that are generated during the kernel compilation. Merely unpacking the kernel source isn't enough.

With kernels built with the `CONFIG_MODVERSIONS`, the version number can differ, but the layout of the data structures must be the same. This option is activated in the Ubuntu kernels. With this option, in addition to the headers, modules need to be compiled against the proper `Module.symvers` file. CentOS, like most distributions, includes this file in the same package as the kernel headers resulting from the compilation. The CentOS kernel header package is called `kernel-headers`; make sure to install the version that matches the kernel you're compiling for. See also [Overview of kernel packages](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-kernel-packages.html) in the CentOS documentation and [You do not need the full kernel source](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source#head-7cb967afe95d0c9be0f9f1e1b874ecad494cb6ba) on the wiki.

With kernels built without the `CONFIG_MODVERSIONS` (which may be the case if you compiled your own kernel), the check when loading a module is a simple version check. You can take the unpacked kernel source, copy the `.config` that was used during the compilation of your running kernel, and run `make modules_prepare`. The onus is on you to verify that any patch you've made to the kernel doesn't affect binary compatibility.

Comment: We know all this, but it doesn't solve the problem. The problem is that for many people recompiling the kernel would be catastrophic. Hence why they want to avoid it alll costs. Think problems with undocumented device trees, and all sorts of issues.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you download the 2.6.32 kernel?

If you use CentOS then just install sources of your kernel `2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64` from CentOS repository, since RedHat uses patched kernel. Please also make sure that configuration of the kernel source tree you build against is exactly the same as of running kernel.

Usually there are `config-*` files at `/boot/` directory or you could try to get the config of the running kernel from `/proc/config.gz`.

You could also refer to official CentOS HowTos:

- http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source
- http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Custom_Kernel

Comment: I downloaded source from www.kernel.org

Comment: @SGG As I said, you need the sources from your distribution, because RedHad-like distros usually don't use standard kernel.

Comment: But i want to compile my module with standard kernel

Comment: @SGG Do you want to test it with standard kernel as well? The thing is that you cannot compile it with standard kernel and run with yours; These versions (compiled/running kernel) should match.

Comment: no alternate??? So i have to download new kernel, build it for hours?

Comment: @SGG: No, you don't have to build the entire kernel. There is a development RPM (`kernel-headers`? `linux-devel`? Something like that) which you can build against. You will need to have a CentOS 6 machine to build on, since you won't be able to install that RPM on a different type of Linux. If you only have one physical machine, set up a CentOS VM for this cross-compilation task. Bottom line, UVV is right: you can't build on one system and distribute that `*.ko` file to other Linuxes. You have to build on a system that is at least *close* to the one you want to install on.

Comment: Exactly. You need the kernel `2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64`

Comment: they are giving rpm files. how can I configure the source? I want to edit the source and compile

Comment: @SGG: Who is "they," and what RPM files are they giving you? And, what does it matter what someone else gives you? Set up a VM, build the `*.ko` file on that, and send the other person the module file you built. Or, send them the kernel module source and have them build it on *their* machine.

Comment: http://pkgs.org/centos-6/centos-updates-x86_64/kernel-headers-2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64.rpm.html are giving RPM file. My doubt is I want kernel source, where I can change few lines. So that i can run my modules with that changed kernel.

Comment: [The first link above](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source) explains this.